# Sharepoint get SPWEB group right

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to get group right on a SPWEB?
I made script who get all groups in collection but I need to get right by SPWEB.

spweb1.com => admin = full control/ group2 = read
spweb2.com => admin = full control / group3 = read / group3 = collaborate
...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking but just incase I am right

This script will return a list of all sites, the groups and the permissions the groups have.

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$sites = get-spsite | get-spweb
foreach($site in $sites) {
    write-host $site.URL -ForegroundColor Green
    $site.associatedgroups | select name, roles
        write-host ""
}